# 2D loops for building a table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops

I want to loop through a two-dimensional structure in angularjs to display it in a table. The data looks as follows:

```
data = {
    "keyA": ["valueA", "valueB"],
    "keyB": ["valueC", "valueD"]
}
```

the output should look like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>keyA</th>
        <td>valueA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>keyA</th>
        <td>valueB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>keyB</th>
        <td>valueC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>keyB</th>
        <td>valueD</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

at the moment my angular enriched html doesn't work and looks as follows:

```
<table>
    <div ng:repeat="(key, values) in data">
    <div ng:repeat="value in values">
    <tr>
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        <td>{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
    </div>
    </div>
</table>
```

In this case I'm using the `<div>` element, but it doesn't work because obviously a `<div>` doesn't belong into a `<table>` like that. Is there some find of a No-Op-Element, which I have to use for loops like this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's possible. Maybe someone can be a little more creative then I. You could try something like this though:

Controller-

```
var data = {
    "keyA": ["valueA", "valueB"],
    "keyB": ["valueC", "valueD"]
};

$scope.getPairs = function() {
  var ret = [];

  for(var key in data) {
    for(var i = 0; i < data[key].length; i++) {
      ret.push(key, data[key][i]);
    }
  }

  return ret;
}
```

HTML -

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="pair in getPairs() track by $index">
      <td>{{pair[0]}}</td>
      <td>{{pair[1]}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add `ngRepeat` on `<tr>` and `<tbody>` element:

```
<table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="(key, values) in data">
        <tr ng-repeat="value in values">
            <th>{{key}}</th>
            <td>{{value}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0h4UTYqPhjLpAYXLTaUs?p=preview)

Comment: <th> elements should be present on <tr> inside <thead> element